# Realm Gradle 'examples' project refresh failed

Tags: android, realm

I have downloaded realm example projects from [Github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java)

I Imported that project.

Finally I got this below error.

**Realm Gradle 'examples' project refresh failed**

```
Error:Could not find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    file:/Users/govindaraj/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/Users/govindaraj/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    file:/Users/govindaraj/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
    https://jitpack.io/io/realm/realm-gradle-plugin/1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/realm-gradle-plugin-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Required by:
    io.realm:encryptionExample:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the snapshot repository in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<version>-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will check it and let you know @EpicPandaForce

Answer (score 1):

If you cloned our entire repo, you need to run `./gradlew assemble` from the top-level directory first. It could probably be stressed more in our README